# How to reduce lambda expression

Tags: haskell, lambda

I am reading the book "Haskell from first principles". On page 12 we are learning how to reduce lambda expressions.

[image]

What I do not understand is why the period character between λz and (λm.λn.m) disappeared in step 3. When I substitute x with (λm.λn.m) in step 3, I thought that only x should be substituted and not the period in front of it. So I would have expected
(λy.λz.(λm.λn.m)z(yz))(λp.p)
instead of
(λy.λz(λm.λn.m)z(yz))(λp.p)

Here is my analysis

---

1. (λxyz.xz(yz)) (λm.λn.m) (λp.p)

   Make currying explicit.
2. (λx.λy.λz.xz(yz)) (λm.λn.m) (λp.p)

   Substitute x=(λm.λn.m)
3. (λy.λz.(λm.λn.m)z(yz)) (λp.p)

   Substitute y=(λp.p)
4. (λz.(λm.λn.m)z((λp.p)z))

   We now observe that λz has no arguments. So what remains is to reduce (λm.λn.m)z((λp.p)z)
5. (λm.λn.m) z ((λp.p)z)

   Substitute m=z
6. (λn.z) ((λp.p)z)

   Here we have λn.z (something). But λn.z of anything is just z. (Since the body of λn.z is just z which does not contain n)
7. z

   Remembering λz in front from step 4, we end up with
8. λz.z

   So we end up with the same answer as the book.

Comment: I don't have a copy of this book, but could it be a typo? (If the period mysteriously reappears in the next step, then this would seem to be most likely.)

Comment: The lambda notation with periods is really fiddly and prone to this kind of typo. I don't understand why people don't write (λx⟼λy⟼λz⟼xz(yz))(λm⟼λn⟼m)(λp⟼p), or just use Haskell notation (\x->\y->\z->xz(yz))(\m->\n->m)(\p->p).

Comment: As I understand it Alonzo Church wrote λx(something) instead of λx.something. The advantage of using Church notation is that you see where the body begins and where it ends.

Comment: @BobUeland The usual convention is that the scope extends to the right as much as possible. So, a λx binds x until the first closed parentheses or the end of the term. IMO, it's nice to be able to write e.g. λxyz.xz(yz) without additional parentheses. For some reason, I prefer the dot to the more noisy `->`. Church introduced the terms using the notation `λx[M]` and `{F}[M]`, but then immediately wrote "a formula `λx1[λx2[...λxn[M]...]]` may be abbreviated as `λx1x2...xn.M` or as `λx1x2...xnM`" [Church36]. The latter is a little ambiguous. At that time he did not abbreviate `a(b)` as `ab`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's positively, definitely, surely a typo.

Comment: If it is a typo then what does the expression reduce to. The answer in the book is λz.z. Is that correct?

Comment: @BobUeland testing it quickly on GHCi, seems so. `let f = (\x y z -> x z (y z))(\m n -> m)(\p -> p)`, `:info f` => `f :: t -> t`. (That's only the type information, but given the expressions involved, I'd think it could only be  `\x -> x`).